# releasing Glib::RefPtr

Tags: gtk, gtkmm

How can i release the pointer sourceImage after finishing using it.

```
Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Pixbuf> sourceImage = Gdk::Pixbuf::create_from_file(inSourcePath.c_str());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned, you don't need to release it.  Just let the RefPtr go out of scope and it will be released automatically.  However, if for some reason you *do* want to release it manually, you can simply call `sourceImage.reset()`

Answer (score 0):

You [don't](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-memory-shared-resources.html.en) release it.

> When [object] goes out of scope an unref()
>   will happen in the background and you
>   don't need to worry about it anymore.
>   There's no new so there's no delete.